# How to install PyCrypto for Python 3.9?

Tags: python, installation, module, package, pycrypto

My question is: how to install PyCrypto on windows and python 3.9? When I typed `pip install pycrypto` to the commandline(cmd or powershell) I get an Error.

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\My Username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\My Username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mg3qxtu2\\pycrypto_ffaf716f631d47a5a2b1a2cfaf5a949e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\My Username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mg3qxtu2\\pycrypto_ffaf716f631d47a5a2b1a2cfaf5a949e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\My Username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7ovjz48d\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\My Username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pycrypto'
         cwd: C:\Users\My Username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mg3qxtu2\pycrypto_ffaf716f631d47a5a2b1a2cfaf5a949e\
    Complete output (183 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -Ic:\users\My Username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\My Username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/winrand.obj
    winrand.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "intmax_t"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "rem"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(29): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "}"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "imaxdiv_t"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ")" vor Bezeichner "_Number"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "_Number"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(43): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ")" vor Bezeichner "_Numerator"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "_Numerator"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ","
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(49): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(57): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(64): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(70): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(77): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(83): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(90): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(96): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\My Username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\My Username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mg3qxtu2\\pycrypto_ffaf716f631d47a5a2b1a2cfaf5a949e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\My Username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mg3qxtu2\\pycrypto_ffaf716f631d47a5a2b1a2cfaf5a949e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\My Username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7ovjz48d\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\My Username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pycrypto' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've already tried to install pycryptodome(x), but if I try to import it, I get an Error(Module not found)

Answer (score 0):

Please first review about pycrypto and its compability to your current python version.

pycrypto Released: Oct 17, 2013

PyCrypto is written and tested using Python version 2.1 through 3.3. Python 1.5.2 is not supported.
For additional information please visit - https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/

Steps:

1. First activate your virtual env and
   if you already install pycrypto Uninstall it with
   pip uninstall pycrypto
2. Install pycryptodome as replacement of pycypto
   pip install pycryptodome

   or
   pip install pycryptodomex
3. If you use splunklib then below step will helpful

   pip install splunklib --no-deps
4. Go to your env variable and update METADATA, in my case
   \mypython-project\my-env\Lib\site-packages\splunklib-1.0.0.dist-info\METADATA
   [image]
   Edit METADATA and replace "Requires-Dist: pycrypto" with "Requires-Dist: pycryptodome" if you use pycryptodome
5. If you want to install splunk-sdk and splunklib then use below command

   pip install splunk-sdk

   pip install splunklib